# Visual Studio Code Markdown preview styles

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, markdown

I know how to use *markdown-styles* in settings to supply my own CSS for styling Markdown previews, but I don't know what elements and CSS classes to style. Are the ones used in Markdown preview documented somewhere?

Answer (score 10):

1. Open a Markdown file.
2. Open the split preview window (<kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd> on Mac, or the split view icon in the upper right-hand corner of the window, or open the command palette (menu *View* → *Command Palette* or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Cmd</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> on Mac) and run *Markdown: open Preview to the side*.
3. Open the command palette and run *Developer: Open WEBVIEW developer tools*.
4. That will open a browser-like inspector, and you can drill down and see whatever you need there.

Note that *Toggle Developer Tools* in the *Help* menu does not work for this — it does not drill down into the Preview's webview window.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **vr8ce**’s helpful answer to find the source of the default stylesheet. On the Mac, this is the path:

`/Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/extensions/markdown-language-features/media/markdown.css`

Comment: Brilliant, thanks - on Windows you can find it at: C:\Users\${USERNAME}\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\markdown-language-features\media

The location may vary according to how you install it

Comment: Good info Oly Dungey. Translated slightly for pasting into the Run dialog (Win-R) on Windows:

%LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\extensions\markdown-language-features\media